# Python combine 2 un nested for loops to get result

Tags: python, list

Why is my code below not working correctly? The answer for `d3` is getting calculated incorrectly. I want `d3` to be `[-1,1,3]` but instead I am getting `[1,2,3]`. How can I fix this code?

```
x = [1,2,3]
z = 3 
y = [4,5,6]
d =[]
for i in range(3):
    d1 = x[i]-z # [-2,-1,0]
for j in range(3):
    d2 = y[j]-z # [1,2,3]
    d3 = d1+d2 # [-1,1,3]
    d.append(d3)
for i in d :
    print (i)
```

Comment: Please specify how you want to correctly calculate d3

Comment: Your variable ```d1``` will not be ```x[i]-z``` while using ```d3 = d1+d2```

Comment: Please provide information on what you want the code to do, What what is your logic for it and what is the error you are facing.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/broken/

Comment: @prnvbn d3 should be [-1,1,3] instead i am getting [1,2,3]

Comment: Or `d=[xx+yy-2*z for xx, yy in zip(x, y)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must iterate over a list and get the sum you want:

```
x = [1,2,3]
z = 3 
y = [4,5,6]
d =[]
d1 = []
d2 = []
for i in range(3):
    x1 = x[i]-z # [-2,-1,0]
    d1.append(x1)
for j in range(3):
    y1 = y[j]-z # [1,2,3]
    d2.append(y1)
    
for k in range(3):
    d3 = d1[k] + d2[k]
    d.append(d3)
for i in range(3):
    print(d[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at what you have commented in your question as to what the lists look like, I think this is what you require:

```
x = [1,2,3]
z = 3 
y = [4,5,6]
d1 = [(e - z) for e in x]   # [-2,-1,0]
d2 = [(e - z) for e in y]   # [1,2,3]
d3 = [ a + b for a, b in zip(d1, d2)]  # [-1,1,3]

for i in d3:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
-1
1
3
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand the context, but if you want `d3` to be `[-1,1,3]`. You need to place both `d1` and `d2` within the same loop.

```
x = [1,2,3]
z = 3 
y = [4,5,6]
d =[]
for i in range(3):
    d1 = x[i]-z # [-2,-1,0]
    d2 = y[i]-z # [1,2,3]
    d3 = d1+d2 # [-1,1,3]
    d.append(d3)
for i in d :
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a need for the second 'for' loop.
This achieves what I think you are looking for:

```
x = [1,2,3]
z = 3 
y = [4,5,6]
d =[]
for i in range(3):
    d1 = x[i]-z # [-2,-1,0]
    d2 = y[i]-z # [1,2,3]
    d3 = d1+d2 # [-1,1,3]
    d.append(d3)
for i in d :
    print (i)
```

When you start a second 'for' loop to iterate indexes of 'y', you are only going to get the last index of 'for' loop iterating over 'x'.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using one list comprehension:

```
x = [1,2,3]
z = 3 
y = [4,5,6]

d = [a + b - z*2 for a, b in zip(x, y)]
```

Or for a numpy approach (which is overboard but what the heck)

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3])
z = 3 
y = np.array([4,5,6])

d = x + y - z*2
```